# store closures in an array

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++11

I would like to store some closures in an array.
I tagged the question MSVC10 since it seems that according to c++11 closures should be compatible (at least under some conditions) with function pointers but MSVC10 does not supports that.

Is there a way around this limitation?

example:

```
  typedef double (*Func)(const C* c);

  struct Feature{
    Feature(FeatureId i_id = None, const QString& i_name=QString(), Func i_ex = nullptr)
      :id(i_id),name(i_name), extraction(i_ex)
    {}
    FeatureId id;
    QString   name;
    Func      extraction;
  };

  QList<Feature> features;

  features.append(Feature(feat_t, "a/t", [](const C* c) -> double{return c->a.t;} ));
```

I want to be able to assign closures to the function pointer because i do not want to define dozens of separate functions.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `std::function<double(const C*)>` (see [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)) instead of `Func`, so

```
 struct Feature{
    FeatureId id;
    QString name;
    std::function<double(const C*)> extraction;
   /// etc...
 };
```

You may need to upgrade your compiler (I guess that Visual Studio 2010 appeared *before* the [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) standard, but I never used Windows or other Microsoft products). Did you consider using a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (4.9 at least) or a recent [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/) (3.5) ?

If you cannot upgrade your compiler, stick to C++98 and don't use C++11 features.

By definition, a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29) is more heavy that a function pointer, since it contains *closed values* (some of which might be hidden or non-obvious).

Comment: thanks. that works.  if i would have free choice of compiler i would use a more recent one. But I am bound to that specific environment.

Comment: Then don't use any C++ closures and code in a C++98 style (not a C++11 one)